# Out of range value for column Oracle to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, oracle, .net-3.5

I am synchronizing a huge database from it's oracle datasource to a mysql datasource for other purposes. When reading the data using PuTTY in a linux/oracle database the value is

```
8888888888
```

This is stored into an object and then inserted in MySQL and then ends up becoming

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008888888888
```

Now I am unfortunately no programming hero and I can't seem to figure out the problem. The datatype in both databases is int(10) and the C# Application does no no way tamper with any values. Here is the actual error message: (omitted irrelevant parts of the statement)

```
Error while executing query 
INSERT INTO tsdsmd(kode8) 
VALUES ('00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008888888888')
Out of range value for column 'kode8' at row 1
```

Could it be a charset mismatch?

This is the code that builds the insert command

```
public int Insert(string table, string[] fields, object[] values)
{
    if (fields.Length != values.Length)
        throw new DBException("Field lengt is not equal to values length!");

    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    query.Append("INSERT INTO ");
    query.Append(table);
    query.Append("( ");
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
    {
        query.Append(fields[i]);

        if (i != fields.Length - 1)
        {
            query.Append(", ");
        }
    }

    query.Append(") VALUES (");

    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
    {
        query.Append("@" + fields[i]);

        if (i != fields.Length - 1)
        {
            query.Append(", ");
        }
    }

    query.Append(")");

    DBCommand command = new DBCommand(query.ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
    {
        command.AddParameter("@" + fields[i], values[i]);
    }

    return Insert(command);
}
```

Edit; I have changed some of the code and I am now skipping those rows for the while being with a separate try catch. Have a look and this is what I am seeing. The value shoudl be within the bounds of an int and I am so confused. Potential bug? The error it gives me that the int is too small or too large for an int32. Which should not be the case.
[image: Code screenshot]

Comment: `This is stored into a string` Why? How?

Comment: Sorry to muddy up your post Davide.  I am replying on my iPhone.  Are the 0's being added to the insert statement?

Comment: @Brian No they are not. I added the C# code that creates the insert statemnt.

Comment: @Sebas We output an excel file with PuTTY, which gives us <name> <type> <length> for every column in a table and type is N, A N2, S2, etc. The type in this case is N, which is the equilivant of an integer and that is the column that is created in mysql. The application allows me to create mysql tables and add synchronization rules which let me synchronize across different database types/environments.

Comment: @ppeterka I'll update the question. It is stored into an object.

Comment: @Sebas: Oracle does understand the datatype `integer` (you can use it in a `create table` statement). It's simply an alias for `number(22)`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60926/1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Aha! While number(22) and i the xls it just says "N" rather than N22 or something similiar. That is where the problem lays. Number(22) is also way larger than int32 or int in mysql?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes but INT(10) fails. That was my point. The whole thing was to point out anyway that that putty extract is irrelevant.

Comment: @Sebas The oracle database specifies number(10) and the old application sees N(10) as INT(10). Something that wasn't considered in the plan of attack many years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the column in oracle is not limited by int32 like "int" from mysql is.  Will have to convert the mysql column to int64/long.

Comment: Note to self: 888888 value in kode8 was bogus test data apparently. Thanks db administrators.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like you may need to explicitly cast the value when adding the parameter. The value your code is trying to insert is the wrong data type and zero-padded, but it's technically correct. It should fix the problem if you do this:

`command.AddParameter("@" + fields[i], (int)values[i])`

Admittedly, that will be a bit of a pain if you're trying to deal with multiple data types dynamically, but it shouldn't be too tough to add a few tests to figure the value's proper data type.

Comment: Strange, it claims conversion is invalid. I'll look further into this.

Comment: Maybe try an explicit conversion instead of a cast? My c# skills aren't super, so I may be doing this wrong.

Comment: Casting it does not seem to be the issue. I'm using convert, cast and parse but they all seem to return leading 000's for some reason.

Comment: The problem is that 888888888 is larger than what int32 supports. Still cannot find out why it adds 000000000's when querying mysql.